# Confused by the number of hits received for a search query through Twitter4j?

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

Below is the code that I use for searching,

```
Query query = new Query( queryStr );
query.setCount( 100 );
QueryResult result = twitter.search( query );
List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
```

I issued two queries: Q1 = "twitter text research" and Q2 = "twitter research" and I the code above returned 100 and 65 results for the two queries respectively. Since all the results for Q1 valid for Q2 (since search results are identified by keyword matching) why the number of hits for Q2 is only 65? What's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I get more than 100 result from the two queries, but just like you I get less results with the longer query
Keep this in mind from the Search API [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)

> Before getting involved, it’s important to know that the Search API is focused on relevance and not completeness. This means that some Tweets and users may be missing from search results. If you want to match for completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead.

For Twitter if you add "text" at your Query you just get less relevant results. The Search API isn't for completeness.

**Edit**

 If you want to get more than 100 results you need to move to the next "page"

```
 Query query = new Query( queryStr );
    query.setCount( 100 );
    QueryResult result;
    do {
        result = twitter.search(query);
        List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
        for (Status tweet : tweets) {
            System.out.println("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
        }
    } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
```

If you only want to know how many tweets you receive, you need to call

```
System.out.println(result.getCount());
```

Comment: it's giving me 100 (as 100 is my limit) now when I check the 2 queries again. But I have no idea why that happened (it can't be due to the fact that search api is more on to relevance than completeness as i get 100 results now)..?

Comment: I just update my answer, so you could know how to get more than 100 tweets, and yeah I believe that the results are more on to relevance than completeness, if you want completeness you should move to the streaming API

Comment: apologies for the late reply..yes i know how to use paging to dig down deeper. But do you have any idea how twitter search works? How does it incorporate relatedness when matching tweets for a query?  I guess it's just based on keyword matching?